ffmpeg in windows oprating system giving error just after execution of change bit rate of audio
`I am changing the bit rate to 124 bitrate at the calling ffmpeg in change bit function it returns error to postman, and still code running also it uploading the file to s3
i want that it does not return error at the time of calling fuction changeBitrate it returns internal error and even it also upload file also please tell why this is happening and on windows system.
`
  try {
    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No audio file uploaded' });
    }

    const audioData = req.file.buffer;
    const tempFile = `${Date.now()}.mp3`;
    await fsPromises.writeFile(tempFile, audioData);


    const compressedFileName = `compressed_${tempFile}`;
    await changeBitrate(tempFile, BITRATE, compressedFileName);

    let url = '';
    if (fs.existsSync(compressedFileName)) {
      url = await audioFileToS3('xyz', 'audio', compressedFileName);
    }
    await fsPromises.unlink(tempFile); 
    await fsPromises.unlink(compressedFileName); 
    return url;
  } catch (error) {
    log.error({ error: error });
    throw error;
  }
};
async function changeBitrate(inputFile, bitrate, outputFile) {
  try {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ffmpeg(inputFile)
        .audioBitrate(bitrate)
        .on('end', () => {
          console.log('Bitrate changed successfully!');
          resolve();
        })
        .on('error', (error) => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
          reject(error);
        })
        .save(outputFile);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

